# How set language parametr to WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I set a language parameter in `WP_query` for filter language?
`'suppress_filters' => 0` is not working.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'apre_restaurants',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following script

```
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'tax_query' => array( array( 'taxonomy' => 'include custom taxonomy name', 'field' => 'id', 'terms' => function_exists('icl_object_id')?icl_object_id($categoryID,'include custom taxonomy name',false):$categoryID ) ), 'suppress_filters' => 0 ); //(do not forget 'suppress_filters' => 0) :)
```

Comment: $artists = new WP_Query('post_type=artist&orderby=rand&posts_per_page=9&suppress_filters=1');